# Insert custom data from form to custom table on wordpress database

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I wanna create some form for users to subscribe to our article and store the data in the database. I know that some plugin can do that but I don't know how to create the validation when the user already subscribed and the form never shows again.

How should I do to insert the data into my database?

Thank you!

**the form**

```
                    <form action="<?php echo site_url() . '/insert-data.php'; ?>" method="POST" name="form-subscribe">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p>Name*</p>
                                <input type="text" name="subs_name" placeholder="Full Name*" required="">                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p>Email*</p>
                                <input type="text" name="subs_email" placeholder="Email Address*" required="">                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitForm">Submit</button></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**the action file aka insert-data.php**

```
<?php

    //setting up the form
    function insertuser() {

      $name   = $_POST['subs_name'];
      $email  = $_POST['subs_email'];  

      global $wpdb; 
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "subscriber";
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('subs_name' => $name, 'subs_email' => $email) );
      }

if( isset($_POST['submitForm']) ) insertuser();

?>
```

**Here is the table of wp_subscriber**
[image]